# MQTT subscribe not working in Android

Tags: mqtt, paho

I am trying to get a message from the MQTT Broker using the Android service, but it does not work.

The library used is the Paho MQTT library, and the source code is as follows.

```
final MqttConnectOptions hIoTConnectionOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
hIoTConnectionOptions.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1);
hIoTConnectionOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
hIoTConnectionOptions.setCleanSession(false);`

try {
    hIoTAndroid = new MqttClient(ip_addr, clientID, new MemoryPersistence());
    IMqttToken conToken = hIoTAndroid.connectWithResult(hIoTConnectionOptions);
    hIoTAndroid.setCallback(MqttMessagingService.this);
    conToken.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess");
            hIoTAndroid.setCallback(MqttMessagingService.this);
            try {
                IMqttToken subToken = hIoTAndroid.subscribeWithResponse(subtopic, 1);
                subToken.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribe to: " + subtopic);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't subscribe to: " + subtopic);
                    }
                });
            } catch (MqttException | NullPointerException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed Connection");
        }
    });
} catch (MqttException ex) {
    Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Connection attempt failed with reason code = " + ex.getReasonCode() + ":" + ex.getCause());
}


@Override
public void connectComplete(boolean reconnect, String serverURI) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection is established....");
}

@Override
public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
    Log.d(TAG, "The Connection was lost,,");
}

@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
    Log.i(TAG, new String(message.getPayload()));

}

@Override
public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Sent Message !");
}
```

The publish and deliveryComplete functions work fine, but the subscribe function and messagArrived do not work. Why?

Comment: I have same problem with `org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.1` and the token returned by `subscribe` call is `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This problem is solved.

Comment: Subscriber is not working because you have not set Mqtt call back  client_subscribe.setCallback(this);